# complex htaccess rewrite rule needed?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would love some help for a complex apache htaccess rewrite rules.
I have three cases for naming php files and they are:
X-Y-Z.php, X-Y.php and X.php (example foo-bar.php - X-Y.php). 
I would like a rule that could rewrite X/Y/Z request into X-Y-Z.php file and every other case too. Is this rule possible?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-$2.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1-$2-$3.php
```